# Как в java выполнить код через секунду?

Tags: java, таймер

Здравствуйте. У меня возник вопрос насчет таймеров в Java, как мне сделать так, чтобы вывод сообщения производился через одну секунду? В инете посмотрел, но ничего толкового не нашел.

```
if (message.toLowerCase().contains("привет") ||
  message.toLowerCase().contains("здравствуйте") ||
        )

 {

String[] cats = {"Привет!", "Привет, дорогой друг!", "Приветствую тебя!"};
            getTextarea.appendText(cats[rand.nextInt(cats.length)]+"\n"); } //Вот эту строку нужно выполнить через секунду
```

Comment: Какую GUI-библиотеку используете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your code here
                }
            }, 
            1000 
    );
```

После того, как последняя ссылка на объект Timer исчезнет, ​​и все задачи завершены, поток выполнения задачи таймера заканчивается и становится объектом сбора мусора. Однако это может занять некоторое время.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @AidenProgrammer, в таком случае пометьте ответ, как правильный, зеленой галочкой.

Comment: таймер для задержки? ..... минимум скобок много и слишком увесисто